# Is Ubuntu safe from USB hacks when lock screen is on?

Tags: usb, security, encryption, lock-screen

Is Ubuntu safe from USB hacks (e.g. similar to badusb and usbdriveby) when the lock screen is open?

For example,are new USB devices prevented from being enabled and from accessing the system when the lock screen is on?

In case it matters, I am on Ubuntu 16. Thank you.

Comment: This sounds a little bit of an X-Y problem.  BadUSB is a firmware-level attack and lock screens can't help with that.  I don't know enough about usbdriveby to give an accurate assessment.  You also need to split individual questions into individual questions as the questions you're asking are not related to each other (fimrware-level protections vs. encryption vs. ...)

Comment: Not sure what the purpose is in plugging in a USB and having lock screen on to do nothing at all, except as you propose to be hacked by the USB but Voting to Reopen as you satisfied @ThomasWard request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sole purpose of the lock screen is to prevent physical access to a running user session through human interface devices (keyboards, mice, displays…). It doesn't prevent any interaction with system and session services through other means. That means that the kernel will still enumerate new USB devices and send notifications about them to udev which in turn will do things like to load appropriate kernel modules or start a service related to the device.

Moreover, the lock screen doesn't prevent any interaction between (new) USB devices the system *firmware* (e. g. the BIOS) which is what BadUSB targets.

Bottom line:

- If you want to safeguard against firmware attacks, upgrade vulnerable firmware or don't use the hardware built upon it.
- If you want to safeguard against USB attacks against the operating system (kernel and user space services), disable the specific udev rules that enable them – or disable all udev rules related to USB to prevent any interaction between the operating system and USB device<sup>1</sup> without the explicit action of a super-user.

  <sup>1</sup> except enumeration which is harmless when implemented correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have found usbguard which helps me to mitigate concerns about unauthorized usb devices plugged in while log screen is on (and also when it is not). https://github.com/dkopecek/usbguard